# deviseでメール送信ができない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, gmail

私は、railsの学習を初めて、3ヶ月の初学者です。

今、deviseを使って、ユーザー管理機能を実装しようとしています。

パスワード再設定用のメールを送りたいのですが、エラーが出て送ることができません。

```
config/environments/production.rb
Rails.application.configure do
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'EC2で発行してもらったIPアドレス' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port => 587,
    :domain => 'gmail.com',
    :user_name => ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
    :password => ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"],
    :authentication => 'plain',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :openssl_verify_mode  => 'none',
  }
```

production.logを見てみると、Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at)というエラー文が出ていたので、検索してみて、いろいろ試してみました。

まず、gmailのセキュリティの設定が高いのが問題だという記事を見つけたので、セキュリテイを下げてみたのですが、エラー文に変化なし。
上記のコードの環境変数のところを直書きしてみても変化なし。
plainのところをログインにしてみても、変化なし。
いっこうに解決しません。

かれこれ５時間ほどすったもんだしていて、万策尽きたという感じです。
どんな些細な点でもいいので、ご教授頂ければ幸いです。

Comment: 「いろいろ試してみた」の具体的な内容と結果を質問を編集して追記してください

Comment: suzukisさんコメントありがとうございます。
私が初心者過ぎて、ネットに落ちている記事の切り貼りで制作しようとしているのが根本の原因です。
基本から勉強頑張ります。